# Adding text below the markers using \addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following image:

[image]

I would like to add text below the markers. I didn't find any solutions yet.

This is how I generated the plot:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Scale vs. Performance},
    xlabel={Number of MLP Blocks},
    ylabel={Top-1 Accuracy (\%)},
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    xtick={0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10},
    ytick={0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100},
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (2,64.89)(4,68.38)(6,69.0)(8,68.68)(10,72)
    };
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Search for `nodes near coords`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like that:

I named the first mark `A1` in your plot with `\node[below] at (axis cs:2,64.89) {A1};`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Scale vs. Performance},
    xlabel={Number of MLP Blocks},
    ylabel={Top-1 Accuracy (\%)},
    xmin=0, xmax=10,
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    xtick={0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10},
    ytick={0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100},
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=red,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (2,64.89)(4,68.38)(6,69.0)(8,68.68)(10,72)
    };

    \node[below] at (axis cs:2,64.89) {A1};
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]